# Проход всех элементов в БД через сервис

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных, android-service

Я пытаюсь написать программу. Сейчас у меня появилась проблема с сервисом, который берет информацию лежащую в БД. Мне нужно, что бы сервис брал информацию каждого элемента, проводил с ней некоторый манипуляции, затем брал следующий элемент. Когда он пройдет все элементы, он опять должен начинать считать с первого. Когда я запускаю программу, в этом месте мне выдает ошибку. Программа дальше работает, а сервис - нет. Вот код сервиса

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    db = new DB2(this);
    db.open();

    cursor = db.getAllData();


    c();

}
void c(){
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        String[] from = new String[] { DB2.COLUMN_DAY, DB2.COLUMN_MONTH,DB2.COLUMN_YEAR,DB2.COLUMN_HOUR,DB2.COLUMN_MINUTE};
        int[] to = new int[] { d110,m110,y110,h120,min120 };
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,0,cursor,from,to);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        //Здесь идет подсчет времени. Его убрал, что бы не занимал код много места

        };
        updateThread.start();
        super.onCreate();
    }
    else
        c();
}
public void not (){
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TEST2.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки, думаете, не нужен тем, кто будет отвечать на ваш вопрос? Для исправления нажмите ссылку `править` ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Я знаю. Забыл добавить, что текста ошибки нету в логе

Answer (score 2):

Вам явно нужно перечитать любой из туториалов как правильно писать сервисы для Андроид. Ошибки что я вижу в коде:

- Вызов `super.onCreate()` больше одного раза
- "Тяжелые" операции в `onCreate()`
- Попытки прямо "достучаться" до UI thread из сервиса

Я бы Вам посоветовал сделать все через `IntentService`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html
Приложение стартовало, послало интент, дожалось ответа, послало снова. И так хоть до бесконечности.

Comment: ага, и каждый раз нужно будет создать ваш  IntentService

Comment: Сам по себе IntentService это всего лишь один обьект :) Но все зависит от того что он сам создает, тут соглашусь.